# How many subsets of $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ are there?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Not sure I believe there are 8 subsets but do we treat a set inside a set as one element? So should it be 2 subsets?

Comment: Is $1$ and element of $\{A\}$ where $A=\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: Any set with a single element has two subsets: the empty set and itself.

Comment: Any set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets. This set has $1$ element/

Comment: 1 is an element of {1,2,3} yes but I'm talking like what does {{1,2,3}} mean exactly? is it 2 subsets or 8 because {1,2,3} has 8 subsets

Comment: @SportsPlanet The set has $1$ element. The one element is $\{1,2,3\}$. $1$ is NOT an element of $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Comment: ok makes more sense

Comment: So would {{1,2},3} have 4 subsets then?

Comment: @SportsPlanet Yes

Answer (score 2):

This is a singleton set whose only element happens to be a set. So the power set has $2^1 = 2$ elements, in this case $\{ \}$ and $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$S=\{....\}$ means that any object $x$ belongs to $S$ iff $x$ is equal to something "named" in the "$....$". So $S=\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ means that $x\in S\iff x=\{1,2,3\}.$ There is exactly one object that is equal to $\{1,2,3\}.$ So $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ is a set with $one$ member.

Answer (score 0):

How many subset of $\{A\}$ are there?

Answer: $2$.   $\emptyset$ and $\{A\}$.

Now does it matter what $A$ is?  No.  It doesn't.  $A$ could be an elephant; a number; the planet Earth; a glass of wine.  Whatever it is, it is one thing.

$A$ is always a single element and the only subsets of $\{A\}$ are the one that contains $A$ and the one that doesn't contain $A$.

So what if $A =\{1,2,3\}$?  That's *one* thing.  A set. The set may have things inside it, but the set is one thing.

Is the set $\{A\}$ and the set $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ different things?

Answer: No, they are not.  If $A=\{1,2,3\}$ than $\{A\} = \{\{1,2,3\}\}$.

How many elements does $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Answer:  It has one element.  That element is $\{1,2,3\}$.

But what about the elements *within* $\{1,2,3\}$?

They have nothing to do with anything.  The set $\{A\}$ has two subsets no matter what $A$ is.  $A$ could be an elephant; a number; the planet Earth; a glass of wine; or a set with three elements inside it.  Whatever it is, it is one thing.  And a set with one element has $2$ subsets.  The *element* is a set we don't have to worry about the elements *within* that set, any more than if it were the planet Earth we'd have to worry about the individual elephants and glasses of wine (and other things) living on it.

If we consider the planet Earth as one thing we don't count or consider the individual things within the Earth.  And if we consider $A = \{1,2,3\}$ as one thing, we don't have to consider the individual things within $A$.